# FormRequest that renders JS content in scrapy shell

Tags: scrapy, dynamic-content

I'm trying to scrape content from this [page](https://registers.maryland.gov/RowNetWeb/Estates/frmEstateSearch2.aspx) with the following form data:

I need the `County:` set to Prince George's and `DateOfFilingFrom` set to `01-01-2000` so I do the following:

```
% scrapy shell
In [1]: from scrapy.http import FormRequest                                                                                                                                          

In [2]: request = FormRequest(url='https://registers.maryland.gov/RowNetWeb/Estates/frmEstateSearch2.aspx', formdata={'DateOfFilingFrom': '01-01-2000', 'County:': "Prince George's"})                             

In [3]: response                                                                                                                                                                     

In [4]:
```

But it's not working(response is None) plus, the next page looks like the following which is loaded dynamically, I need to know how to be able to access each of the links shown below with the following inspection(as far as I know this might be done using `Splash` however, I'm not sure how to combine a `SplashRequest` within a `FormRequest` and do it all from within scrapy shell for testing purposes. I need to know what I'm doing wrong and how to render the next page(the one that results from the `FormRequest` shown below)

[image: search results]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request you're sending is missing a couple of fields, which is probably why you don't get a response back. The fields you fill in also don't correspond to the fields they are expecting in the request. A good way to deal with this is using scrapy's from_response ([doc](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#using-formrequest-from-response-to-simulate-a-user-login)), which can populate some fields for you already based on the information in the form.

For this website the following worked for me (using scrapy shell):

```
>>> url = "https://registers.maryland.gov/RowNetWeb/Estates/frmEstateSearch2.aspx"
>>> fetch(url)
>>> from scrapy import FormRequest
>>> req = FormRequest.from_response(
...             response,
...             formxpath="//form[@id='form1']", # specify the form on the current page
...             formdata={
...               'cboCountyId': '16',  # the county you select is converted to a number
...               'DateOfFilingFrom': '01-01-2001',
...               'cboPartyType': 'Decedent',
...               'cmdSearch': 'Search'
...             },
...             clickdata={'type': 'submit'},
...       )
>>> fetch(req)
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution works perfectly fine, I need help with triggering JS event to land on the next page, please check my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63563676/how-to-trigger-a-js-next-page-event-using-scrapy)

Comment: Like always @Wim Hermans is the one and only for scrapy issues!♥
One question i would like to ask: If i pass my formdata into the shell, every lines begins with the "...", but i need to fetch again, how can i "finish" my command so i can use the fetch command? Hope it could point out what i tried to say, thanks in advance :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean - if you just press enter your shell should go back to '>>>' so you can write new commands. If it stays on '...' you're probably missing a parenthesis or a quote.