# How to trigger a JS ASP.Net next page event using scrapy?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, scrapy, dom-events

I'm scraping content off this [website](https://registers.maryland.gov/RowNetWeb/Estates/frmEstateSearch2.aspx) I start by sending a `FormRequest` that yields the search result based on [Wim Herman's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8794009/wim-hermans) answer on my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63556512/formrequest-that-renders-js-content-in-scrapy-shell)

I scrape what is needed and want to move to the next page which does not consist of a url, it's triggered by JS. Here's how the html tag looks like:

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('dgSearchResults$ctl24$ctl01','')">2</a>
```

I tried the following and nothing seems to work:

```
In [18]: fr = FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata={"__EVENTTARGET": 'dg
    ...: SearchResults$ctl02$ctl03'})                                           

In [19]: fetch(fr)                                                              
2020-08-24 16:47:06 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://registers.maryland.gov/RowNetWeb/Estates/frmEstateSearch2.aspx> (referer: None)

In [20]: view(response)                                                         
Out[20]: True
```

and this:

```
In [21]: fr = FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata={"__EVENTTARGET": 'dg
    ...: SearchResults$ctl02$ctl01'}, clickdata={'type': 'submit'})             

In [22]: fetch(fr)                                                              
2020-08-24 16:50:24 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://registers.maryland.gov/RowNetWeb/Estates/frmEstateSearch2.aspx> (referer: None)

In [23]: view(response)                                                         
Out[23]: True
```

when I view the response, it either lands me on the initial page (the one containing the initial form) or just nothing happens, the page number is still set to 1.

Comment: This is quite common in ASP Net pages. The `from_response` is great for handling those but sometimes it skips mandatory fields, or **include fields that shouldn't be in the body of the request**. Try inspecting your `request.body` before you yield it and compare it with the body of the POST request your browser makes when changing the pages. If it is the same, you might need to reproduce the headers as well.

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: Sure, will write an proper answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mention in the comment this is pretty common issue on ASP Net pages. As you probably know by now the js you mentioned will trigger a POST request. The body of this post request may contain fields that you filled in your search form as inputs and several hidden inputs generated by the page instance (like `__VIEWSTATE` or `__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR` ).

When you use the `FormRequest.from_response()` method it will search for those inputs to fill the request body, it does that by selecting all input elements inside the `//form` element in the page. Sometimes that's ok, sometimes it isn't, that's your case.

When the method selects all inputs, it gets an input that was meant for something else. In your case it is this input:

```
<input id="cmdSearchNew" value="New Search" ... />
```

### How would you know?

If you use your browser's dev tools and analyse how the request is made to change from page 1 to 2 you will see that it's a POST request and it's body is something like this:

```
{
    "__EVENTTARGET":"dgSearchResults$ctl24$ctl01",
    "__EVENTARGUMENT":"",
    "__VIEWSTATE":"jyAD4Bm...",
    "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR":"11C1F95B",
    "__EVENTVALIDATION":"TmG0xFB..."
}
```

However, if you inspect the body of your scrapy request (*you can print your `fr.body` in the shell you are already using*) you will see somethng like this:

```
{
    "__EVENTTARGET":"dgSearchResults$ctl24$ctl01",
    "cmdSearchNew": "New Search"
    "__VIEWSTATE":"jyAD4Bm...",
    "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR":"11C1F95B",
    "__EVENTVALIDATION":"TmG0xFB..."
}
```

*It will be urlencoded, this is a parsed view*

That `cmdSearchNew` field shouldn't be there, it's meant for something else, but scrapy couldn't know that as it was inside the same form. (Also `__EVENTARGUMENT` won't be there because the value is empty, so Scrapy will ignore it)

Once you identified the problem, you can tell the `from_response()` method that you don't want a specific field to be in the body, by setting it to `None`.

```
fr = FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata={
    '__EVENTTARGET': 'dgSearchResults$ctl24$ctl01',
    'cmdSearchNew': None
})
```

This should be enough for you to get the response for page 2.

Comment: I did set the field to be None. But it is still getting passed in the form request. Any ideas why?